# EC2 has detected degradation of the underlying hardware

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I received an email from amazon aws

> EC2 has detected degradation of the underlying hardware hosting your
> Amazon EC2 instance (instance-ID: i-xxxxxxxx) associated with your AWS
> account (AWS Account ID: xxxxxx) in the us-west-1 region. Due to this
> degradation your instance could already be unreachable. We will stop
> your instance after 2021-05-28 04:00:00 UTC. Please take appropriate
> action before this time.

the instance itself is working fine at the moment but this email doesn't sound friendly.
what am i supposed to do this point. we are using docker and node on this instance.

Comment: Is the docker ECS/EKS, or are you running something custom that starts Docker?

Comment: Stop the instance, then restart it, which will bring it up on new hardware.

Comment: @MarkB , is that all? restarting with resolve the issue? no further action?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stopping the instance then starting the instance should migrate the VM off the degraded hardware.  Note that you shouldn't "reboot" or "restart" it.  You need to full stop, then start it.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-degraded-hardware/

Comment: unfortunately, i had restarted the server by reading the comment reply.
can i still stop and start the server ? would this still resolve my issue?

Comment: Yes, full stop, then full start.

Comment: The best, short and to the point answer! Thank you

Comment: Is there any data loss?

Comment: You should not lose data during a full stop and start.  Typical applications should gracefully exit upon receiving the notification that the OS is shutting down.

Comment: Do we need to do https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/safely-drain-node/ in case of EKS?

Comment: Follow any best practices based on the applications that are running.